# net use command works in cmd, but not powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm running a simple

`net use N: \\myserver\myshare`

It works fine in cmd, but not powershell where I want to run the script.
When I run it from CMD the drive shows up in the explorer. When I run it in PS, it does not.
Doesn't matter if I run as admin or not.

Why is this?

Comment: Could you show the error message you get when you attempt to use `net use N: \\myserver\myshare`

Comment: It completes the command, but the drive doesn't show up in the file explorer. It does however if I run the command from CMD.

Comment: Are there any unusual characters like brackets?

Comment: I can't replicate this on Windows 10 using PowerShell 5.1. `net use N: \\localhost\c$` sets up a new global drive pointing to the local machine's C. To make absolutely sure that you're hitting the right command and not an alias, try explicitly using `net.exe` as the command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you try to map a drive in an elevated PowerShell session. You'll need to map any persistent drives from an unelevated session. Similarly, any mapped shares available in File Explorer aren't available in an elevated PowerShell session, either.